# JUnit running a final test?

Tags: java, maven, junit

There are so many posts about running JUnit tests in a specific order and I fully understand:

1. Tests should not order specific
2. and that the creators did this with no 1 in mind

But I have test cases that creates a bunch out output files. I need to capability to have one final test that goes and collects these files, zip it and emails it of to someone.

Is there a way to group JUnit tests together for me to have a "wrap up" group that goes and do this? Or is there a better way of doing this?

I am running these from Jenkins as a maven job. I could create another job that does just that based on the previous jobs output but would prefer if I can do it all in one meaning I would be able to run it everywhere even from my IDE.

Comment: Those tests are called integration tests. If you need to have an order in there the best is not to use JUnit cause it does not support this. Use TestNG for such kind of this...

Comment: You are correct. I am using Junit with cucumber to do the integration test with the output in a custom report file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the real problem is that you want the results and output of the tests sent via email.
Your suggestion of using a test for this threw me on the wrong track.

Definitely use some sort of custom Jenkins post hook to do this. There are some fancy plugins that let you code groovy which will do the trick.

Do not abuse a unit test for this. These (should) also run locally as part of builds and you don't want that email being sent every time.

Comment: We are already getting so many test emails that it is not even funny. :) Will for sure using Jenkins to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) and [@AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) annotations are what you are looking for:

```
@AfterClass
void cleanupClass() {
    //will run after all tests are finished
}

@After
void cleanup() {
    //will run after every test
}
```

However, I would consider handling this through Jenkins if possible. In my opinion the annotations above are for cleaning up any kind of setup that was previously done in order to do the testing.

Sending these files through email does not sound like part of the testing and therefore I would be inclined to keep it separated.

Comment: Using jenkins sounds like a good idea... The tests write the files, then jenkins collects and emails them, cleaning up afterwards. Sounds reasonable and better than adding infrastructure work into unit tests.

Comment: Thx - I am already doing some cleanup in each test case. Will stick with Jenkins then